# Is there a category-theoretic definition of induced subquivers (subgraphs, subposets etc.)?

Tags: category-theory

Let $Q=(V,E)$ denote a [quiver](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quiver) and suppose $V' \subseteq V.$ Then (definition:) $V'$ gives rise to an "induced subquiver" of $Q$, call it $Q'$ simply by defining that $Q' = (V',E')$ where $E'$ denotes the maximum subset of $E$ such that every element of $E'$ has both its source and its target in $V'$.

Indeed, the same basic idea works for induced subgraphs and induced subposets, too.

**Question.** Suppose $Q$ is an object of a category $\mathcal{C}$ and $U : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$ is a functor, and furthermore assume that $f : V' \rightarrow U(Q)$ denotes an injective function. Is there a way to define "the subobject of $Q$ induced by $f$ with respect to $U$"? I want it to give the correct answer for the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of quivers (graphs, posets etc.) and $U$ is the forgetful functor.

Comment: Is the notion of a topological concrete category what you want? http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, perhaps. It will take me a while to digest the definition.

Comment: Are you sure you're interested in [concrete categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category)? Because quivers shouldn't be concrete in nlab sense.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa, why wouldn't they be concrete? The forgetful functor $\mathrm{Pos} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$ is certainly faithful.

Comment: @user18921 damned hurry in digitation, I meant quivers :P My bad.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa, oh hey, you're totally right.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q \in \mathcal C$ and $f \colon V' \to U(Q)$ an injective function (i.e. a monomorphism in $\mathbf {Set}$.

Then we can consider the following subcategory $U^{-1}(f)$ in which:

- objects all those monomorphisms $p \colon X \to Q$ in $\mathcal C$ such that $U(p)=f$;
- for every pair $p \colon X \to Q$ and $p \colon Y \to Q$ in $U^{-1}(f)$ a morphism $g \colon p \to q$ is just a morphism $g \colon X \to Y$ in $\mathcal C$ such that $q \circ g=p$ and $U(g)=1_V$;
- composition and identities are the obvious ones.

In this category every morphism $g \in U^{-1}(f)(p,q)$ is a monomorphism, since $q \circ g=p$ in $\mathcal C$ and $p$ is a monomorphism of $\mathcal C$.

The terminal object in $U^{-1}(f)$ should be a good candidate to be the subobject generated by $f$.

This works fine you categories, meaning that in these cases the terminal object is (up to isomorphism) the subobject generated by $f$ (that's because in the categories you've considered subobjects are monomorphisms, up to isomorphism, they admit an epi-mono factorization).

A further generalization could be made by considering a sub-category of inclusions in $\mathcal C$ and requiring that objects and morphisms of $U^{-1}(f)$ are inclusions, that is objecs and morphisms of the subcategory of $\mathcal C$. Of course the construction above become a particular case when you consider a subcategory formed by the monomorphisms of $\mathcal C$.

I suppose that the subcategory of inclusion should verify some properties, but I'm not so sure about which ones.

Comment: @user18921 is this what you were looking for?

Comment: It looks about right. Strange that it doesn't work for quivers though. I'm going to leave the answer unaccepted for a while just to see if someone can iron this final issue out.

Comment: By the way, I think better notation than $U^{-1}(f)$ would be $U^{-1}(f,Q)$ or some such, since $Q$ is very much part of the definition of this category.

Comment: Or perhaps $U^{-1}_{\rightarrow Q}(f).$

Comment: @user18921 I don't know which version you've seen, but the construction in the last one works for quivers too.

Comment: The reason why I called this category $U^{-1}(f)$ is because in the case of concrete categories (where the functor $U$ reflect monomorphisms) the construction is simply the fiber of the object $f \colon V \to U(Q)$ in the slice category $\mathbf{Set}/U(Q)$ through teh functor induce by $U$ between the slice categories $\mathcal C/Q$ and $\mathbf {Set}/U(Q)$.